# Topological description for graph minors

Tags: graph-theory, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

In the following content, graphs are considered inside $ZFC$ as the $1$-dimensional CW-complexes deduced from its cardinal-valued (multigraphs may have cardinals larger than $1$ as entries) adjacent "matrix" (*which means no edges intersect at non-vertices although it may seem to*), the size of which may also be infinite cardinals. In this sense, subgraphs precisely correspond to closed subcomplexes. For simplicity an answer about **the finite case** is welcome.

There are two main partial orders defined on graphs: Given two graphs $G$ and $H$, $H$ is a *topological minor* of $G$ iff $H$ is isomorphic to the subgraph of some finite-step subdivision-and-smoothing of $G$, and $H$ is a *minor* of $G$ iff $H$ is isomorphic to the subgraph of some finite-step edge-contraction of $G$ (*here, a one-step edge-contraction is operated on **a single edge** connecting **two different vertices***). The former has a nice topological description - $H$ is a topological minor of G iff $H$ can be topologically embedded into $G$ (at least true for finite graphs) - while the latter, despite being manipulated in a topological manner, is seldom considered topologically. This qustion concentrates on a possible topological description of the latter and ask for verification.

Observe that a graph $G$ has a canonical CW-epimorphism to its finite contraction by mapping the closure of the contracted $1$-cells to the result $0$-cells. Moreover, this epimorphism is in fact a homotopy equivalence (each contraction is a topological quotient by a contractible subspace). So $H$ is a minor of $G$ only if **$H$ can be topologically embedded into some graph $G'$ that admits a surjective homotopy equivalence from $G$**. Does the inverse (the "if" direction) also hold true? The subtle point is that the "if" direction does not require the surjective homotopy equivalence to be a CW-morphism to involve no more information outside the $Top$ category.

Comment: In your second paragraph defining minors, you made no restriction on the edges that are contracted during the finite-step edge-contraction. How then can you conclude that "each contraction is a topological quotient by a contractible subspace"?

Comment: @LeeMosher A one-step contraction is, by definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#Formal_definition), operated on a **single** edge connecting two **different** vertices, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Then you should edit your post to be more self-contained, saying explicitly what you mean by a one-step contraction and by a finite-step edge contraction. (You should not generally expect your readers to know a wikipedia definition, especially given the undependability of wikipedia definitions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the case that $G$ is an infinite graph is false. Take for instance the following graph $G$ embedded in $\mathbb R^2$:
$$G = (\mathbb R \times \mathbb \{0\}) \cup (\mathbb Z \times [0,1])
$$
There is a quotient map $f : G \to G'$ which maps the entire line $\mathbb R \times \mathbb \{0\}$ to a single point and is otherwise one-to-one. The graph $G'$ is a star graph of countably infinite valence, meaning it has one vertex of countably infinite valence, connected to countably infinite vertices of valence $1$. Both of $G$ and $G'$ are contractible, hence $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. Taking $H=G'$, it follows that $H$ can be topologically embedded into some graph $G'$  that admits a surjective homotopy equivalence from $G$. However, $H$ is not isomorphic to any subgraph of some finite-step edge-contraction of $G$, because in any finite-step edge contraction of $G$ every point has finite valence.

---

But the case where $G$ is a finite graph does seem to be true. The proof requires one to understand all possible surjective homotopy equivalences $f : G \to G'$. First, since $G$ is compact and $H$ is Hausdorff, the map $f$ is a quotient map. The map $f$ induces a decomposition of $G$, and lets consider $Q$ to be the collection of nontrivial decomposition elements, i.e.
$$Q = \{f^{-1}(y) \mid y \in G', |f^{-1}(y)| > 1\}
$$
Each element of $Q$ is an embedding of a finite tree into $G$, because otherwise $f$ would not be a homotopy equivalence. There are countably many components of $Q$, and those components are pairwise disjoint. Define $C(G) \subset G$ to be the union of all edges of $G$ that are contained in $Q$, so $C(G)$ is an actual subgraph, and each of its components is a tree. You can now collapse the edges of $C(G)$ one-at-a-time to get a quotient graph $G \mapsto G''$, but what happens here is that $G''$ is isomorphic to the graph $G'$. So now it is true: if a graph $H$ can be topologically embedded into $G'$, then it can be topologically embedded into $G''$ and so $H$ is a minor of $G$.

Comment: Careful, the sentence says "EACH ELEMENT of $Q$ is an embedding of a finite tree into $G$". And the meaning is only a topological embedding (nonetheless, by subdivision along finitely many points one could turn it into a graph embedding).